# How can I get the user to input more than one value at a time in C#

Tags: c#, prompt

I am prompting the user to enter their first middle and last name in one prompt.
So if they type for example John Ronald Doe, how can I take those values from that one string and assign them to fname, mname, lname, to create a person constructor that takes these values.

Basically my question is how to take multiple values in one prompt for a user and then assign them to different variables for a constructor.

Thank you!

Comment: Please be aware that [not everyone has a first, middle, and last name](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: yes, for simplicity I wrote the question with one, having no middle name is considered. thanks though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just grab the line then split on white spaces. You'll have to do some input validation to make sure they actually enter `fName mName lName` but I'll leave that to you because what you do is dependent on how robust the application needs to be. By that I mean, what happens if the user only enters two words? Do you just assume it's first and last name and set their middle name to `String.Empty` ? What happens if they enter 4 or 5 words?

```
string[] tokens = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

if (tokens.Length == 3)
{
    // do assignment
}
```

With regard to your comment;

That is more or less correct. Really what's happening is `ReadLine()` is returning a string. I'm just calling `Split(' ')` directly on that result. You could break it into two lines if you'd like but there's no reason to. `Split(char delimiter)` is an instance method in the `String` class. It takes a char and returns an array of strings. I'm using tokens because it's kind of a common term. The line is build of three tokens, the first, middle, and last names. It's important to understand that I am not adding anything to an array, `Split(' ')` is returning an array. `string[] tokens` is just declaring a reference of type `string[]`, I don't have to worry about the size or anything like that.

An example to get an array of ints from the input. Note, if any of the input is not a valid integer this will throw an exception.

```
  int[] myInts = Console.ReadLine.Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

In this example I'm using LINQ on the result of the split. Split returns a string array. `Select` iterates over that array and applies the lambda expression I pass it to each of it's values. It's best to think of `x` as the current value. The `Select` call here is roughly equivalent to;

```
List<int> myInts = new List<int>();
foreach (string s in tokens)
{
    myInts.Add(int.Parse(s));
}
int[] myIntArray = myInts.ToArray();
```

If you can't trust the user input you should use `TryParse`. I don't know if you can use that as part of a lambda expression (it wouldn't surprise me if you could but it seems like a pain in the ass so I wouldn't bother) instead I'd do;

```
List<int> myInts = new List<int>();
int temp;
foreach (string s in tokens)
{
    if (int.TryParse(s, temp)
        myInts.Add(temp);
    else
       // the input wasn't an int
}
int[] myIntArray = myInts.ToArray();
```